# Javascript Validation for required fields

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and in a form validation example
I found this :
To check for required field

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="")
   {
   alert("First name must be filled out");
   return false;
   }
 }
```

I have two questions :

1. In what case the input value could be null (x==null) and in what case input value is empty       (x == "") ?
2. Why is return being used ? Is it necessary ? Is there a case where we return true ?

Answer (score 2):

> **In what case the input value could be null (x==null) and in what case input value is empty (x == "") ?**

`null` means the name doesn't have any reference of any object. where `""` means an empty string.
in your case you will get `null` if there is no element. and `""` when its value is empty string.

> **Why is return being used ? Is it necessary ? Is there a case where we return true ?**

mostly return false is used to to stop the proccessing, if return is false we will no go further

***go to this link for example***
 http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/404274/Client-Side-Validation-using-JavaScript

Comment: Yeah but if the user  leaves a text field blank, what would it return "" or null ?

Comment: It'd return "" not null.

Comment: but in my js code I have simply used if(x){ //do stuff}else{//alert} and it is showing alert when field is left blank

Comment: `if (x)` in both cases of `null` and `""` will go to the `else` part. Check this `!(!("")) == false` and `!(!(null)) == false`.

Comment: so basically the condition if(x) is simply checking whether the value is null or not, but you said when the field is left blank it should return "" not null. So how is this going in the else part ?

Comment: `if (x)` will check the boolean value of `x`, and both `""` and `null` are treated as `false` boolean values. To check what is the boolean value of a variable/value do evaluate this `!(!(value))` and you'd get if it maps to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add to @lol answer that the `return false;` used here is probably used inside some event, like `onSubmit` for the `<form>` element in your HTML, this will ensure that the form isn't submitted. In general `return false;` will tell the browser not to continue with the default behavior such as submitting a form, or navigating to a page, etc.

Comment: is it always necessary to use "return false" in case of invalid inputs ?

Comment: Usually you don't want to submit the form if it's not valid.